# Colour lost in legend when printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, dygraphs

I have a Dygraph with its LabelsDivId set to a div on my page. The on-screen display is fine.

[image]

But, when I print it, the graph is in colour but the labels become black.

[image]

Why are the labels losing colour on print?

I haven't given any code here, I'm assuming there's something fundamental I've missed.

EDIT:

I should point out that I am using CutePDF to grab the print image, but the colour loss occurs when I print to a real printer too.

EDIT.

I should have tried this at first. It prints OK in Google Chrome and Firefox, it is only in IE that this occurs. Any ideas how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I had:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

Removing this line makes the legend print in colour as expected.

I may still need this line, I put this in ages ago. I think I needed it for the Dygraph to display in IE8. As I am working in IE11 I will accept this answer for now.